# How to reduce size of customized scroll bar in Sublime Text 3

Tags: material-design, sublimetext3, scrollbar

I have customized my scroll bar by referencing one answer from stackoverflow.

This is my Material-Theme-Darker.sublime-theme file

```
[    
    // More visible scrollbar
    {
        "class": "puck_control",
        "layer0.texture": "User/theme_override/scroll_puck.png",
        // Optional: set to your desired RGB color
        "layer0.tint": [141, 234, 255],
        "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
        "layer1.opacity": 0.0,
        "layer0.inner_margin": 2,
    },
    {
        "class": "puck_control",
        "attributes": ["horizontal"],
        "layer0.texture": "User/theme_override/scroll_puck_horiz.png",
    }
]
```

[image: This is result of customized scroll bar]

But the scroll bar is quite bold and I want it to be short in width so can anyone tell me how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the scrollbar narrower, you need to edit `User/theme_override/scroll_puck.png` and `scroll_puck_horiz.png` so that it is narrower. Then, set `"content_margin"` to something like this:

```json
"content_margin": [8, 12],
```

and play around with the first number until you get a width you like.

Comment: Can you tell me how to reduce size of bottom scrollbar?

Comment: @VedikaDorugade you do the same thing, just decrease the height of `scroll_puck_horiz.png`, then add `"content_margin": [8, 12],` to the rule and adjust the values as needed.